# Swift ARM64: Understanding how types such as URL and String are stored in memory

Tags: swift, arm64, disassembly

Im trying to understand how string parameters get passed into Foundation.URL.init and also how the resulting URL is stored in memory. I've captured a few screenshots that demonstrate what im working with.

Im reversing this simple swift code I wrote:

[image]

So here is before the branch to swift.string.init:
[image: Before executing swift.string.init]

At this point, our registers look like this:

[image]

X1 has the value 0x1F which is 31 in decimal, the length of the string we are initialising.
X2 has a value of 1 indicating that this value is an ascii value

X0 points to memory location 0x10003E40, which looks like:

[image: Mem location]

After branching and returning to link pointer, our registers look like this:

[image]

So we seem to have the length of the string prefixed with a D, D00000000000001F in X0 that we passed as X1 into the previous procedure.

Then when we continue execution to this point:
We do the same thing but with a path component we are appending to the url (AAAAAAAA....):
[image]

Our registers look like this:
[image]

Once again our X0 register points in memory to:

[image]

and our X1 register is set to 0x3A, which 58, the length of the AAAAAA.... string.

After execution our registers look this:
[image]

When we get to this line of the code:

[image]

Our registers look like this:
[image]

We have the value 0xD....1F in X0

A little later afrer url appendingString is called we call the absoluteString getter a.
[image]

Our registers look like this:

[image]

X0 points at 0x16FDFF5F0 which looks like this:

[image]

so this number is stored on the stack 0x600002908000.

My questions are:

1)what does this number (0x600002908000) refer to in memory and how can we examine it's contents?

2. What do the "reference" numbers returned by swift.string.init refer to in memory and how can their contents be examined?

Well that was along one! Phew! Any help in understanding these things would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks!
Chris

Comment: `String` has a number of different storage strategies (e.g. a small string optimization, one for faster bridging to Objective C's NSString, etc.). They're documented throughout the main String-related files https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2d42671c85a5ed957732f775c08b0ee63808a81f/stdlib/public/core/StringStorage.swift#L99-L172 I imagine URL is much the same, so I'd start there.